# How to continue execution when Assertion is failed using intern js

Tags: javascript, selenium, assert, intern, verify

I'm using intern js for automation testing, i'm looking for a trick like verify in nightwatchjs

```
assert.isOk(false, 'this will be false')
assert.isOk(true, 'this will be true ')
```

first assertion was failed and execution was stopped. But i want to continue the further snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript expert, but with most assertion, the program will end the execution flow. Why not use your assert statement inside a try/catch block

```
try {
  assert.isOk(false, 'this will be false')
  assert.isOk(true, 'this will be true ')
}
catch (e) {
  logMyErrors(e); // log failures or do something but don't exit 
}
```

Comment: You'd need to wrap each assert in a try/catch.